# Categories specified in the model are not uploading to the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql-9.1

I want to know what I'm doing wrong as my Categories "name" that I specify on rails console are not uploading directly to my postgresql database.

My first Model (category.rb)file

```
class Category < ApplicationRecord
  attr_accessible :name
  has_many :content
end
```

My Second Model (content.rb)file

```
class Content < ApplicationRecord
  attr_accessible :title, :body, :category_id, :author_id
  belongs_to :category
end
```

I've added two categories inside this model

"Football" and Cricket using the code below:

```
category = Category.create(:name => "Football")
category = Category.create(:name => "Cricket")
```

The above code creates category id and tables in the postgresql not the name I specified.

Please help.. Please reply if you need anything else

Comment: Add your migration files.

Comment: Have you done `rake db:migrate`? It sounds like you've added the "name" column after creating the table definitions but haven't migrated.

Comment: Which version rails?

Comment: My version is rails 5.0.2

Comment: i.stack.imgur.com/CAooY.jpg Please use this link to view the result when I create a category, no name uploading in my database.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Category < ApplicationRecord
  attr_accessible :name
  # has_many :content -- This is wrong
  has_many :contents # This is how it should be
end
```

Also has hashrocket suggested try running migration.
What is the result of running the following in console?

```
c = Category.new
c.name = "football"
c.save
```

If this gives you an error then going through the error message will show what is wrong.

Comment: I've tried running db:migrate, but it hasn't given any errors or any comments.

Comment: Also I've tried running your comment to create category, it runs fine and creates a category id, not the name.

Comment: What error does it give you when you do c.save in console?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CAooY.jpg  Please use this link to view the result of your code c=Category.new